# facebook share count - problem with FQL with different URLs

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I have a plugin on my page which allows users to share articles on my site on facebook, but each url is appended with their user id.

What I want to do is count the number of total share regardless of the shareers user id.

However I cannot get the FQL to work as the where parameter will not accept the LIKE function..

the pages will be something like:

page1.php?sid=2
page1.php?sid=34
page1.php?sid=12

But I want to retrieve the total shares for page1.php regardless of the sid.

The LIKE function doesnot work in FQL does anyone have any ideas as I am struggling

current code:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.que … ge1.php%27

Answer (score 1):

You can use FQL to make your query :

```
$fql = 'SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://google.com"';
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->total_count;
```

Here, `total_count` gives you the number of shares for the link.

If you have several URL to query, you can make all of that in only one query by using `OR` :

```
SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="..." OR url="..."
```

Here is an example is you want to get the number of shares for theses 3 URLs :

```
$urls = array(
    "http://www.example.com/page1.php?sid=2",
    "http://www.example.com/page1.php?sid=12",
    "http://www.example.com/page1.php?sid=34",
);

function wrap($url) {
    return 'url="' . $url . '"';
}

$fql = 'SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE ';
$fql .= implode(" OR ", array_map("wrap", $urls));

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
$data = json_decode($json);
```

And `$data` is an array of 3 objects with the share number for each URL :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["url"]=> string(17) "http://www.example.com/page1.php?sid=2"
    ["total_count"]=> int(1318598)
  }
  [1] => ...
  [2] => ...
  [3] => ...
}
```

Then you just have to go through the array to make a sum.

Hope that helps !